# How to get dropdown "key" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How can i get the key of drop down? I want to display to the user a selected value in the dropdown according to my "projectCode". code:  (I wrote "key" because I am from c# world)

```
var projectCode = ($(sender).attr("ProjectCode"));
    var dropDown = document.getElementById('ddl2Insert');

    for (var i = 0; i < dd.options.length; i++) {
        if (dropDown.**key** == projectCode) {
            dropDown.selectedIndex = i;

            break;
            return false;
        }

    }
```

thanks a lot :)

Comment: try option id or name

Comment: You're using jQuery, right?  Just do `$('#ddl2Insert').val(projectCode);` (Is there really a "ProjectCode" attribute on your "sender" element?)

Answer (score 0):

You need `dropDown.options[ dropDown.selectedIndex ].text`

Comment: Seems like `options[i]` would make more sense here.